# How do I generate a model scaffold in golang-revel?

Tags: go, revel

I read the documentation and spent 2-3 hours playing around with revel.

However I wasnt able to generate a model controller view similar to the booking example in https://github.com/revel/examples, which is awesome but hard to reproduce from scratch.

Is there a Revel CLI command line to do something like this?

```
rails generate scaffold Album title:string year:decimal singer:reference
```